# JSF form submits despite validation failure of component

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm using Mojarra, Primefaces 3.4 and JSF 2.1 along with JPA/Hibernate for persistence.

The problem is best described as having a bean and a view along with a custom validator, where I enter a number into a field which has a validator. The validator checks up the field value in a DB through the backend and prevents duplicate objects from being created.

The validation prevents duplicate objects from being submitted on the first submission in all cases. However, there are several times when it will just allow a subsequent (second) submission to go through and be persisted (albeit with a null value for this particular field having the validator)  even though there is a invalidation failure from the first submission.

I'm unable to understand why this is happening, but suspecting something related to scopes. I've tried CDI's @ConversationScoped and @RequestScoped, as well as MyFaces CODI @ViewAccessScoped.

@RequestScoped seems to "solve" this problem but has some other issues, i.e. it cannot be persisted at all after the first invalidation due to (probably) the values not being retained after the first submission. Additionally, there is an AJAX call on the identifier which will attempt to retrieve customer data from another system. In case it succeeds, all other fields should be readonly which is handled through a boolean set during the customer data retrieval process. @RequestScoped cannot handle this as the value gets "lost" after the first submission.

The entire code is quite extensive, please let me know in case there is any specific part of it you would like to see in order to reply to this question.

Clarification in step-by-step manner:

1. Navigate to page.
2. Attempt to create duplicate object by using existing unique identifier and submission.
3. Form along with custom validator error is shown.
4. Second attempt to submit the same page (without reloading the page).
5. Page is successfully submitted and persisted, but the unique identifier is NOT submitted and has null value in the DB.

This does NOT happen every time, which is the confusing part. However it happens in maybe 50% of cases with no pattern that I could detect.

Comment: its unclear from your description, but does this always happen?

Comment: Just to clarify it in step-by-step manner, I updated my original post.

Comment: I would provide a link to a repository which contains a demo which illustrates the issue.